# AWS Signature 4: Chrome Refused to set unsafe header "Host"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to secure an apigateway end-point using Signature 4 to sign the request and access it from Angular4 front-end.

The Signature 4 documentation specifies:
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/signing-requests/) :

> To create your HTTP request in canonical format. The canonical request must include the **host** and x-amz-date headers for requests without a payload, such as GET or DELETE and must also include the content-type header for requests requiring a payload, such as PATCH, POST or PUT."

When I use POSTMAN to sign it works well, but from the Browser it didn't work, because when I try to set the header HOST, chrome throws an error:

> Refused to set unsafe header "Host" http.es5.js:1253

Then if I look in the Request Headers that Chrome send there is no **Host** header, instead there is a **:authority** header.

As I know this is a security concern and there is no way to force Chrome to do it.

There is a way to tell AWS Signature 4 to Consider *:authority* insted *host*?

Or there is other way to get access from the Browser in a secure way? (as I know API GATEWAY do not support Signature V2)

Comment: You shouldn't have any need to *set* the `Host` header -- you just need to *sign* it.  It is set implicitly when you create the request.  Show your code, please.